# An API to use to retrieve similar words from a keyword?

Tags: c#, .net, search, keyword

I'm writing a search engine in C#, retrieving rows from a SQL database. I'd like the search to also include similar words - for example, if a user searches for "investing", the search will also return matches for "investment", or if the user searches for "financial", the search will also return matches for "finance".

How can I retrieve similar words such as these from a search keyword?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're trying to accomplish is known as "Stemming". Read the Wikipedia article for more info:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stemming

Answer (score 3):

What you're looking for is [stemming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stemming). You may want to look at what's available in [Lucene.net](http://incubator.apache.org/projects/lucene.net.html)... although it's also possible that SQL Server supports this natively with full text indexing. Indeed, it looks like it, given [this article](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/learn-sql-server/sql-server-full-text-search-language-features,-part-2/).

Answer (score 1):

If you're using SQL Server you can take advantage of the FREETEXT search, which supports [stemming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stemming):

```
Select * from SomeTable
where FREETEXT(*,'invest')
```

The above searches all columns for all forms of the word invest. It's equivalent to:

```
Select * from SomeTable
where CONTAINS(*,'"invest" or "invests" or "investor" 
                  or "investing'" or "invested" or "investor's" ... )
```

Here's an [MSDN article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/sqlserverfaq/stemming-functionality-in-full-text-search-using-contains) with more examples and documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Additionally, [soundex](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soundex) searching can help find matches with similar phonetics.  This is supported in SQL Server [SOUNDEX() function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187384.aspx).  .NET doesn't appear the have it built-in, but CodeProject has [several implementations](http://www.codeproject.com/info/search.aspx?artkw=soundex).